# Tensorflow keras frozen .pb model returns bad results on android

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers

I created my model using Keras with transfer learning on IncpetionV3, and exported it to a *.pb* file using the following python code:

```
MODEL_NAME = 'Model_all1'

def export_model(saver, model, input_node_names, output_node_name):
    tf.train.write_graph(K.get_session().graph_def, 'out_all2', MODEL_NAME + '_graph.pbtxt')

    saver.save(K.get_session(), 'out_all2/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp')

    freeze_graph.freeze_graph('out_all2/' + MODEL_NAME + '_graph.pbtxt', None,
                          False, 'out_all2/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp', output_node_name,
                          "save/restore_all", "save/Const:0",
                          'out_all2/final_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', True, "")

    print("graph saved!")

export_model(tf.train.Saver(), model, ["input_3"], "dense_6/Softmax")
```

I then attempt to load my model into my Android application.
For my application I have used the following codes to preprocess my image before sending it to *.pb* model. The Bitmap comes from the camera on my phone.

```
//scaled the bitmap down
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, PIXEL_WIDTH, PIXEL_WIDTH, true);

float pixels[] = getPixelData(bitmap);
public static float[] getPixelData(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
    if (imageBitmap == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int width = imageBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = imageBitmap.getHeight();
    int inputSize = 299;
    int imageMean = 155;
    float imageStd = 255.0f;

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    float[] floatValues = new float[inputSize * inputSize * 3];

    imageBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, imageBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; ++i) {
        final int val = pixels[i];
        floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
        floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
        floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    }


    return floatValues;
}
```

Below shows my recognise image code to link to my loaded .pb file on Android

```
public ArrayList<Classification> recognize(final float[] pixels) {

    //using the interface
    //input size
    tfHelper.feed(inputName, pixels, 1, inputSize, inputSize, 3);

    //get the possible outputs
     tfHelper.run(outputNames, logStats);

    //get the output
    tfHelper.fetch(outputName, outputs);

    // Find the best classifications.
    PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
            new PriorityQueue<Recognition>(
                    3,
                    new Comparator<Recognition>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Recognition lhs, Recognition rhs) {
                            // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
                            return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
                        }
                    });
    for (int i = 0; i < outputs.length; ++i) {
        if (outputs[i] > THRESHOLD) {
            pq.add(
                    new Classifier.Recognition(
                            "" + i, labels.size() > i ? labels.get(i) : "unknown", outputs[i], null));
        }
    }
    final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
    int recognitionsSize = Math.min(pq.size(), MAX_RESULTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < recognitionsSize; ++i) {
        recognitions.add(pq.poll());
    }
    Trace.endSection(); // "recognizeImage"
    //fit into classification list
    ArrayList<Classification> anslist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < recognitions.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("classification",recognitions.get(i).getTitle() +" confidence : "+ recognitions.get(i).getConfidence());
        Classification ans = new Classification();
        ans.update(recognitions.get(i).getConfidence(),recognitions.get(i).getTitle());
        anslist.add(ans);
    }
    return anslist;
}
```

From my testing, before I generated my frozen graph model, *.pb* file. The accuracy of my model is quite high. However, when I load it unto my Android app, the prediction results return from my model on Android are all over the place.

I have been testing for a long time and I am unable to find my problem. Does anyone have any insights? Did I generate the wrong *.pb* file? Or did I send the image wrongly to the frozen graph? I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell since I'm not sure of the details of your Keras model, but one of the trickiest parts to get right when porting to another platform are the input image processing parameters. You have `imageMean` and `imageStd` defined, but do you know that they are the same as the Keras model?

To debug this, I'll often try to feed the same image (for example [Admiral Hopper](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/grace_hopper.jpg)) through the Python and on-device code, and make sure I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your image pre-processing steps. Then the problem might be the same as mine. I faced the same problem and I find an answer. It is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474467/export-keras-model-to-pb-file-and-optimize-for-inference-gives-random-guess-on/49582776#49582776) for more clarification. I guess that you did all the steps as mine except the following.

Your problem might be in color channel reversion. `imageBitmap.getPixels` reverses color channels from BGR to RGB. You just need to convert them back to BGR if this is part of the image preprocessing.

use the following code to do so:

```
    floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
 // reverse the color orderings to BGR.
    floatValues[i*3 + 2] = Color.red(val);
    floatValues[i*3 + 1] = Color.green(val);
    floatValues[i*3] = Color.blue(val);
```

Hope it helps,,